How to properly retrieve image from database using Node.JS?
When I extract the base64 image stored in the database, and convert it to a temporary file like this:
        // Send the formatted text and image to Telegram
        const channelId = process.env.CHANNEL_ID;
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('chat_id', channelId);
        form.append('caption', formattedProgrammeDetails);

        // Create a temporary file and write the image data to it
        const { path: tempFilePath } = await tmp.file();
        await fs.promises.writeFile(tempFilePath, programme.ProgrammePicture);

        // Append the temporary file to the form data
        form.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath), {
        filename: 'announcement.jpg',
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
        });

        const base64Image = programme.ProgrammePicture ? `data:image/jpeg;base64,${programme.ProgrammePicture.toString("base64")}` : null;
        form.append('photo', base64Image, {
          filename: 'announcement.jpg',
          contentType: 'image/jpeg'
        });

        await axios.post(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendPhoto`, form, {
            headers: {
                ...form.getHeaders()
            },
            timeout: 60000 // 60 seconds
        });

I get an error saying that the file is corrupted, I'm unable to send the image through telegram bot API, although I can send the image if I'm using an image I uploaded in my folder (locally). When I try to open the corrupted image, there's nothing.
I'm using Railway Free Trial Database (MySQL).
I tried asking ChatGPT what the issue is, but it kept giving me similar code.

This question is somewhat confusing. You are asking how to retrieve an image from a MySQL database, but the code is used for sending an image to Telegram. Maybe [edit] your question and showcase the code for retrieving the image from the database. Crucial details to include are how the data is stored in your database and what kind of SQL/ORM package you are using to retrieve the data.
